# Merge lines with matching first column

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

I've been trying to use awk to merge two files when they have the same first column. Here are my example files:

FileA.txt

```
A2M    1
A4GALT    11
AAAS    35
AAGAB    7
```

FileB.txt

```
A4GALT    2
AAAS    17
AAGAB    7
```

As you can see, the second file is missing the entry for `A2M`. If I am missing an entry, then I want the entry to read `0` in the final output. As so:

```
A2M    1    0
A4GALT    11    2
AAAS    35    17
AAGAB    7    7
```

My lab mate suggested that I use `awk` since `join` isn't working properly for me. With some help, I've come up with this `awk` command:

```
awk -F "\t" 'FNR==NR {h[$1] = $2;next} BEGIN{ OFS = "\t"} {print $0,$2?h[$1]:"0"}' FileB.txt FileA.txt
```

However, my output does not output the `0` when there isn't a match in `FileB.txt` and instead prints nothing. Any idea about what's going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you join two files, it's a job for [`join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/join.html):

```
join -1 1 -2 1 -a 1 -o 1.1 -o 1.2 -o 2.2 -e "0" FileA.txt FileB.txt
```

Where:

- `-1 1 -2 1` defines the fields to join (in both files the 1st)
- `-a 1` to force `join` to print the unpairable lines from `FileA.txt`
- `-o 1.1 1.2 2.2` is the output format
- and `-e "0"` defines the value to store in an empty field

The output:

```
A2M 1 0
A4GALT 11 2
AAAS 35 17
AAGAB 7 7
```

Comment: When I use this method I get this response `usage: join [-a fileno | -v fileno ] [-e string] [-1 field] [-2 field]
            [-o list] [-t char] file1 file2` and my outputted file has nothing in it.

Comment: @stellar01 Your join doesn't support the `-j` flag, you have to use `-1 1 -2 1` instead, I edited my answer

Comment: I'm still getting the `usage` response with the updated code.

Comment: @stellar01 Edited (the -o flag seems also not portable), try again please^^ If it's not working, can you post the output of `join --version`?

Comment: Worked perfectly. I gave up on `join` because I couldn't seem to get it to work, but you found the problem. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @stellar01 You're welcome, yours is a bsd join I think, however this should always apply: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/join.html