# Join multiple pipe delimited files with unequal rows/lines into one based on first column

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

Join multiple pipe delimited files with unequal rows/lines into one based on first column.

Ex:

test1.txt

```
1|1
2|2
```

test2.txt

```
1|4
2|5
3|6
```

test3.txt

```
1|7
2|8
3|9
4|10
```

output:

```
1|1|4|7
2|2|5|8
3||6|9
4|||10
```

Example 2:
test1.txt

```
1|1|2
2|3|4
```

test2.txt

```
1|4
2|5
3|6
```

test3.txt

```
1|7
2|8
3|9
4|10
```

output:

```
1|1|2|4|7
2|3|4|5|8
3||||6|9
4|||||10
```

Comment: or https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226811/117549

Comment: not really, the files can be more than two....and number of columns are not limited to two

Comment: If you join files 1 and 2 you'll get a result. Join that result with file 3. Join that new result with file 4, etc. Maybe not elegant but I don't see why it won't work.

Comment: Not a dupe IMHO. The proposed dupe does an inner join but here we want a full outer join. The accepted answer of the dupe assumes standard POSIX join, and that answer would have to be significantly altered to be able to output the missing fields in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only for the shown case where there are two columns in each file and three files:

```
$ join -t '|' -o0,1.2,2.2 -a 1 -a 2 test[12].txt | join -t '|' -o0,1.2,1.3,2.2 -a 1 -a 2 - test3.txt
1|1|4|7
2|2|5|8
3||6|9
4|||10
```

That is, perform a relational full outer join on the first two files, and join the output of that with the third file in the same way.  It's the `-a 1 -a 2` that makes it a full outer join.  With GNU `join`, you would be able to replace the `-o` option and its option argument with `-o auto`.

This could be generalised in a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# sanity check
if [ "$#" -lt 2 ]; then
    echo 'require at least two files' >&2
    exit 1
fi

# temporary files
result=$(mktemp)  # the result of a join
tmpfile=$(mktemp) # temporary file holding a previous result

# remove temporary files on exit
trap 'rm -f "$result" "$tmpfile"' EXIT

# join the first two files
join -t '|' -o auto -a 1 -a 2 "$1" "$2" >"$result"
shift 2

# loop over the remaining files, adding to the result with each
for pathname do
    mv "$result" "$tmpfile"
    join -t '|' -o auto -a 1 -a 2 "$tmpfile" "$pathname" >"$result"
done

# done, output result
cat "$result"
```

This script relies on GNU `join` for the `-o auto` option, and it assumes that the join will happen on the first `|`-delimited field in each file and that the files are sorted lexicographically on this field.

It joins the first two files, and then adds to the result of that join, once for each remaining file.

First example in the question:

```
$ ./script.sh test[123].txt
1|1|4|7
2|2|5|8
3||6|9
4|||10
```

Second example in the question (note that in the question, the wrong number of empty fields are shown):

```
$ ./script.sh test[123].txt
1|1|2|4|7
2|3|4|5|8
3|||6|9
4||||10
```

If the files are not sorted, then you may sort them on the go (note: switching to `bash` here for the process substitutions):

```
#!/bin/bash

# sanity check
if [ "$#" -lt 2 ]; then
    echo 'require at least two files' >&2
    exit 1
fi

# temporary files
result=$(mktemp)  # the result of a join
tmpfile=$(mktemp) # temporary file holding a previous result

# remove temporary files on exit
trap 'rm -f "$result" "$tmpfile"' EXIT

# join the first two files
join -t '|' -o auto -a 1 -a 2 \
    <( sort -t '|' -k1,1 "$1" ) \
    <( sort -t '|' -k1,1 "$2" ) >"$result"
shift 2

# loop over the remaining files, adding to the result with each
for pathname do
    mv "$result" "$tmpfile"

    # note: $tmpfile" would already be sorted

    join -t '|' -o auto -a 1 -a 2 \
        "$tmpfile" \
        <( sort -t '|' -k1,1 "$pathname" ) >"$result"
done

# done, output result
cat "$result"
```

To allow the user to join on another field (with `-f`), use another delimiter (with `-d`), and use another join type (with `-j`),

```
#!/bin/bash

# default values
delim='|'
field='1'

join_type=( -a 1 -a 2 ) # full outer join by default

# override the above defaults with options given to us by the user
# on the command line
while getopts 'd:f:j:' opt; do
    case "$opt" in
        d) delim="$OPTARG" ;;
        f) field="$OPTARG" ;;
        j)
            case "$OPTARG" in
                inner) join_type=( ) ;;
                left)  join_type=( -a 1 ) ;;
                right) join_type=( -a 2 ) ;;
                full)  join_type=( -a 1 -a 2 ) ;;
                *) printf 'unknown join type "%s", expected inner, left, right or full\n' "$OPTARG" >&2
                   exit 1
            esac ;;
        *) echo 'error in command line parsing' >&2
           exit 1
    esac
done

shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"

# sanity check
if [ "$#" -lt 2 ]; then
    echo 'require at least two files' >&2
    exit 1
fi

# temporary files
result=$(mktemp)  # the result of a join
tmpfile=$(mktemp) # temporary file holding a previous result

# remove temporary files on exit
trap 'rm -f "$result" "$tmpfile"' EXIT

# join the first two files
join -t "$delim" -j "$field" -o auto "${join_type[@]}" \
    <( sort -t "$delim" -k"$field,$field" "$1" ) \
    <( sort -t "$delim" -k"$field,$field" "$2" ) >"$result"
shift 2

# loop over the remaining files, adding to the result with each
for pathname do
    mv "$result" "$tmpfile"

    # note: $tmpfile would already be sorted and
    #       the join field is the first field in that file

    join -t "$delim" -2 "$field" -o auto "${join_type[@]}" \
        "$tmpfile" \
        <( sort -t "$delim" -k "$field,$field" "$pathname" ) >"$result"
done

# done, output result
cat "$result"
```

Testing by rerunning the second example:

```
$ ./script.sh test[123].txt
1|1|2|4|7
2|3|4|5|8
3|||6|9
4||||10
```

Running on the same files, but joining on the 2nd field:

```
$ ./script.sh -f 2 test[123].txt
1|1|2||
10||||4
3|2|4||
4|||1|
5|||2|
6|||3|
7||||1
8||||2
9||||3
```

Doing an inner join:

```
$ ./script.sh -j inner test[123].txt
1|1|2|4|7
2|3|4|5|8
```

Comment: there might be more than two columns...added another example....

Comment: @KarthikReddy See updated answer.

Comment: I urge you  @Kusalananda to coauthor (Stephan Chazlas) a book on linux unix shells & their scripting. It'll be market runaway hit. And then if all the masters here on this site could pool together their expertise n distill into various chapters would make for an advanced version of your first title.

Comment: @Kusalananda just wandering is it possible to do it using awk?

Comment: @KarthikReddy Of course. It would be a bit complex though, and may require a lot of memory if the files are big, unless intermediate results are saved to temporary files.  You would basically have to implement `join` in `awk`.  I will not add this to my answer.

Comment: We can save some file IO with functions: `do_join() { join -t'|' -a1 -a2 -e "" -o auto <(sort "$1") <(sort "$2"); }` then `join_all() { result=$(do_join "$1" "$2"); shift 2; for file; do result=$(do_join <(echo "$result") "$file"); done; echo "$result"; }`

Answer (score 1):

with GNU awk, and your 2nd set of test data

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "|" }
# like the shell's shift function, returns the "former" first field
function shift(    value, i) {
    value = $1
    for (i=1; i<NF; i++) $i = $(i+1)
    NF--
    return value
}
# return a string with a character repeated n times
#    repeat("x", 5) ==> "xxxxx"
function repeat(char, n,       str) {
    str = sprintf("%*s", n, "")
    gsub(/ /, char, str)
    return str
}

FNR == 1 {fn++; nf[fn] = NF - 1}
{
    key = shift()
    data[fn][key] = $0
    seen[key]
}
END {
    for (key in seen) {
        printf "%s", key
        for (f=1; f<=fn; f++) {
            if (key in data[f])
                row = data[f][key]
            else
                row = repeat(FS, nf[f] - 1)
            printf "%s%s", FS, row
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

then

```
gawk -f joiner.awk test{1,2,3}.txt
```

```
1|1|2|4|7
2|3|4|5|8
3|||6|9
4||||10
```